# horizontal scroll when clicking on the navbar links

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, horizontal-scrolling

I just started coding,I ran into a problem somewhere,I have very little javascript knowledge, it's probably too easy, and I can't do it.I'm trying to build a horizontal-scrolling website.I've done the transitions with the buttons, but ***I want to transitions with the links in the navigation bar***.***when I click on the navigation links, I want to go to other sections.*** how can i do ?

**HTML Codes**

```
 <div class="navbar">
        <a href="" class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="" class="logo-img">
        </a>
        <nav class="nav-list">
            <a href="#home" class="nav-link home-btn">HOME</a>
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link about-btn">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link port-btn">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <button class="page-btn left-btn">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="page-btn right-btn">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>

 
        <section class="section-1" id="home">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1 class="section-1-hd">
                        SECTION ONE
                    </h1>
                </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section-2" id="about">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1 class="section-2-hd">
                        SECTION TWO
                    </h1>
                </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section-3" id="portfolio">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1 class="section-3-hd">
                        SECTION THREE
                    </h1>
                </div>
        </section>
```

**Javascript Codes**

```
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 1;


const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

  if(counter1 === 3) {
    Array.from(sections).forEach(section =>{
      section.style.left = "0"
    })
    counter1=0;
    counter2=1;
   
}

  if(counter1 === -1) {
    Array.from(sections).forEach(section =>{
      if(section.classList[0] === 'section-3') {
        return;
      }
      section.style.left ='-100vw'
    })
    counter1=2;
    counter2=3;
   

  };

window.addEventListener('wheel' , (e) =>{
  const deltaY = e.deltaY > 0;

  if(deltaY) {
    counter1++;
    counter2++;
  }else {
    counter1--;
    counter2--;
  }

  console.log(counter1,counter2);

  document.querySelector(`.section-${deltaY ? counter1 : counter2}`).style.left = `${deltaY ? "-100vw" : "0"}`;
  });


  document.querySelector('.left-btn').addEventListener('click' , () => {
    counter1--;
    counter2--;
   document.querySelector(`.section-${counter2}`).style.left = '0';
  });

  document.querySelector('.right-btn').addEventListener('click' , () => {
    counter1++;
    counter2++;
    document.querySelector(`.section-${counter1}`).style.left = '-100vw';
  });
```

***I MAY HAVE WRITTEN A VERY BAD CODE,AND I APOLOGIZE FOR THAT REASON.***

Answer (score 0):

First, we store all of the section elements into an array

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
```

Then, create a function that will navigate or set the current scroll x position to the next or previous section.

```
let index = 0;
function navigate(direction) {
  if (direction === 'next') {
    index = ++index % sections.length;
  }
  if (direction === 'prev') {
    index = (index > 0) ? --index : index;
  }

  window.scrollTo(sections[index].getBoundingClientRect().left, 0);
}
```

This function will increase the current section index by 1 and modulus it by the size of the sections array or decrease by 1 if its greater than 0.

After getting the new section index, we use window.scrollTo(x, y) to navigate to the target sections `left` attribute.

Now, we are done with javascript, lets head back to HTML. Instead using eventListener, it is easier to use `onclick` like so

```
<button class="page-btn left-btn" onclick="navigate('prev')">
  prev
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
<button class="page-btn right-btn" onclick="navigate('next')">
  next
<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

In the `onclick`, we pass in the `navigate` function with 'next' or 'prev' as its argument

And there you have it!

EDIT: For this line

```
index = (index > 0) ? --index : index;
```

This is equivalent to this

```
if (index > 0) {
    --index;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time and answering my question.I couldn't integrate the codes you wrote into my codes because I had very little js experience, but I created a codepen project,if you can check it.I want to switch to Section 1 when I click on the **Home**,to Section 2 when I click on **About**, to Section 3 when I click on the **Portfolio**

https://codepen.io/ibrahimgedik/pen/ZEWRvYV

you can check my css codes because I superimposed all the pages with z index.

**thank you so much again**

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jquery I could offer you a function from my own toolbox. Given a surrounding container where your nav-items are subelements you want to scroll to.

Include jquery (valid on 2020/14/09):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Have a javascript function do the scrolling. Like so, using `.animate(..)`:

```js
/** Will center the scroll-bar of a container onto one of his child elements horizontally.
 * @param id_container: id string of the scrollable container.
 * @param id_target   : id string of the target that is to be centered to.
 *   Should be a child of above container.
 * @param additional_offset: Will be added to the movement computation (pixels).
 * @param scroll_time: Number. Time in ms that the transition should take. 200 is a good value. */
function scroll_to(id_container, id_target, additional_offset, scroll_time)
{
  //> Preliminaries. -------------------------------------------------
  if (additional_offset===undefined) { additional_offset=0; }
  if (scroll_time===undefined) { scroll_time=200; }
  var cont = $("#"+id_container);
  var target = $("#"+id_target);
  //< ----------------------------------------------------------------
  //> Actual strolling scrolling. ------------------------------------
  var site = target.position().left + additional_offset - cont.innerWidth()/2.0 + cont.scrollLeft();
  cont.animate({ scrollLeft: site }, scroll_time);
  //< ----------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

**Btw.:** The whole animation thingy actually is just a bit of sugar. The core solution is in the setting of the CSS property on the surrounding container: `scrollLeft`. See, e.g., here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time and answering my question.All sections cover 100% of the page and overlap with z-index.maybe if I show you my codepen project, you can look at the css codes 

https://codepen.io/ibrahimgedik/pen/ZEWRvYV

you can check here,I couldn't handle it because I'm inexperienced in javascript.
I want to switch to Section 1 when I click on the **Home**,to Section 2 when I click on **About**, to Section 3 when I click on the **Portfolio**

Comment: Ic. Maybe you can use js to dynamically set/remove the css style property 'display: none' as needed. Do this using the onclick events. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: But maybe what you really want to achieve are tabs: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp